# Rails: how to limit preview text when using rich html text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, text, rich-text-editor, redactor

I'm using redactor gem and I want to display preview of the text in a dashboard, however, it displays HTML tags when I use `truncate` method

```
= auto_link(simple_format(truncate(user.notes, :length => 150, :separator => " ")),html: { target: '_blank' })
```

This will display

```
<p><strong>I want to gets this new redactor out</strong></p><p><strong><br></strong></p><p><strong>Can we provide new test?</strong><br><a...
```

When I try something with sanitize:

```
= auto_link(simple_format(truncate(sanitize(trip.notes, :tags => []), :length => 150, :separator => " ")),html: { target: '_blank' })
```

I get this:

```
I want to gets this new redactor outCan we provide new test?linkWoahdWhatordered pairnumber 1number 2
```

Text doesn't look pretty, and its mashed together.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view (erb)

```
<%= raw auto_link(
          simple_format(
            truncate(
              user.notes, 
              :length => 150, 
              :separator => " "
            )
          ),
          html: { target: '_blank' }
        ) 
 %>
```

Comment: raw doesn't do anything. Still showing the html tags

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... I just needed to include `:escape => false`

```
= auto_link(simple_format(truncate(user.notes, :length => 150, :separator => " ", :escape => false)),html: { target: '_blank' })
```